# How can i deploy an app which have made by uisng mern technology on kubernets?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, kubernetes, deployment

I have mern app which is running on my local host , so how can I deploy this on Kubernetes, which MongoDB URL link is set on backend, and how front end interacts with nodejs api?

i am trying to connect mongodb containers services to node js and nodejs services into react containers.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: todo-server-app-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: todo-server-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: todo-server-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: summer07/backend1:1.0
          name: container1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todo-server-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - name: http
        port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
this is my backend yml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mongo:4.0.9-xenial
          name: container1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "0.0.0.0"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: todo-mongo-vol
      volumes:
        - name: todo-mongo-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: todo-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

this is mongo yml
i see logs they mongopod is connected with nodejs pod but wen i use minikubeip and node js serive host in brower i am not able to get respone .
i use to connect in mongo with mongo service and port in nodejs backend

Comment: feel free to update the status of the question by marking it as accepted if below on answers or do upvote if found it helpful....! please ask any doubt in comment if any. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the application to Kubernetes, so for Database **MongoDB** you can use the **operator** to manage the **PODs** and **deployment**.

In Kubernetes **services** internally connect with each other using the **Service-name**. Service forward traffic to Deployment which is backed by the **PODs**.

so if you deployed **mongoDb** database there will be **svc**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
```

so it will be something like

```
const url = `mongodb://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@mongo:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}?authSource=admin`;
```

same goes from **react** to **node js** **service**, service-name is used internally as **DNS**,

```
curl http://node-service:8080
```

you can pass accordingly in your code **node service** as **Host**.

Comment: Can you explain deeply i am able to connect node js to mongodb pod but not able to maek api request..in my node js port is set to 5000 .can you explain me node js service yaml

Comment: share your current config in question that you are trying and issue you are facing.

Comment: how can share you

Comment: update the question with details what are you trying and some details where its failing

Comment: i am able to connect with node pod with mongo pod but when I try to open nodejs ip with a port in the browser show that service is not available

Comment: so your service `todo-server-app` is clusterip service that IP will not be able to accessibel outside of the cluster. so you have to expose the service with type Nodeport or Loadblancer service. check this : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251594/discussion-between-summer-and-harsh-manvar).